# svg code append using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

below svg code for background-img.it work fine in css

```
background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg style="color:white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 21 23"><ellipse fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" cx="13" cy="8" rx="7" ry="7"/></svg>');
```

but i want set using jquery. and i try but something is wrong

```
svgbefore = 'data:image/svg+xml,';
  var svg ='<svg style="color:white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 21 23"><ellipse fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" cx="13" cy="8" rx="7" ry="7"/></svg>';
  var combo  = svgbefore + svg;
var ap = '<style>'+
  'select#currencies {'+
   'background-image:url("'+combo+'")'+

  '}';
'</style>';
```

Comment: I'm confused by your approach, are you just trying to add an svg element to the page or are you updating an element that's already on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

excellently i want to that below have code.Thanks to all for help me.

```
var clr1 = jQuery("select#currencies").css("color");

jQuery("select#currencies").css("background-image","url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg version=\"1.1\" id=\"Layer_1\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" width=\"8pxz\" height=\"5px\" viewBox=\"0 0 8 5\" enable-background=\"new 0 0 8 5\" xml:space=\"preserve\"> <path fill=\""+clr1+"\" d=\"M0,0c0,0,3.4,4.4,3.5,4.4C3.7,4.4,7.1,0,7.1,0H0z\"/></svg>')");
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

keep your style in css :

```
.mystyle{
background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg style="color:white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 21 23"><ellipse fill="red" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" cx="13" cy="8" rx="7" ry="7"/></svg>');
}
```

Use below jquery code:

```
$("select #currencies").addClass("mystyle");
```

Comment: i also try this                            $("body").css("background","url("+combo+")");               and  $("body").css("background",'url('+combo+')');

Comment: Please see the above modified answer.I tested.It is working fine.

Comment: by seeing your id #currencies I would like to say always id should be unique in the page.

Comment: please help me this my site url  https://ghanshyam-prajapati.myshopify.com/